# openCV error while configuring via cmake

Tags: opencv, cmake, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to visualize the data using [ASAP](https://github.com/GeertLitjens/ASAP). While configuring it in cmake, I am getting this error. OpenCV is already installed in my ubuntu system in the folder /usr/local/share.

```
opencv_calib3d opencv_core opencv_features2d opencv_flann opencv_highgui opencv_imgcodecs opencv_imgproc opencv_ml opencv_objdetect opencv_photo opencv_shape opencv_stitching opencv_superres opencv_video opencv_videoio opencv_videostab opencv_viz
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: This does not look like an error to me! Try to compile your project!

Answer (score 0):

This red line probably comes from the [line 3 of ASAP/imgproc/CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/GeertLitjens/ASAP/blob/2ff185754b65cbf2955c07ad05c9fce108ba3cf7/imgproc/CMakeLists.txt#L3).

The [message()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/message.html) macro is used without any flag. This produce an "Important information" message displayed in red in cmake-gui, but in this case, it's not an error. Maybe ASAP developpers should have used `STATUS` mode to print some debug information from CMake script:

```
message(STATUS ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES})
```

Maybe you could send a pull request.